# Is Linux's 'W' command a security breach?

Tags: linux

I was surprised that the out of the box 'W' command on Linux provides so much information without needing any SUDO or admin permissions. In particular, the command shows the command line of each user's current process. This seems to be a huge hole as it could potentially show someone accessing a hidden file (for instance, the command 'vim .ProofThatTheMoonLandingWasFaked.txt'), plain text passwords (yes, I know that should never be an issue since plaintext passwords should never be entered but it still comes up), etc.

Does the out of the box 'W' command constitute a security hole in a system?

Comment: `w` itself isn't responsible for letting you see people's processes; it does nothing you couldn't do already by going through `/proc`, so the question is really about `/proc` being world-readable. (also, hidden files aren't a security measure of any sort; the only use of them is for convenience, but anyone who can list normal files in a directory can also list hidden files)

Comment: Also, a security hole under what threat model? Security holes are when someone can do something that they shouldn't be able to do. `/proc` being world-readable is an intentional decision; if a decision is made to allow a type of access, then the fact that that type of access is allowed is by definition not a security hole.

Comment: @cpast That comment should be an answer.

Comment: @TerryChia I considered it, but it just reduces it to the question "should all users be able to view the details of every process?" (unless you meant the second comment?)

Comment: @cpast Both comments can be combined into a single pretty good (and correct) answer. :)

Comment: @cpast, thanks for telling me about `/proc`. I wasn't aware it existed and it being world readable definitely gets at the crux of the issue. I guess the big question then would be what was the rationale for making `/proc` world readable which (IMO) contains security sensitive information.

Comment: W is not a risk in and of itself. However there might be times, when you'd rather there not be any local users ( lusers ) on the system. In which case, having rusers would be a better path, and the use of web based applications as opposed to shell accounts shields casual users from all this.

Comment: fwiw when I do `w` on a machine I'm logged into twice, it says the other session is `[priv]` (running Debian)

Comment: @ekaj What does `ps aux` say?

Comment: @mincewind "luser" isn't a term for "local user" contrasted with "ruser," it's a term for "stupid/annoying user" pronounced the same as (and partially derived from) "loser."

Comment: So I just ran the 'W' command on a widely used system. Somebody is running the command 'vim poop.py'. This isn't just a security issue, I don't want to know that (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`w`, by itself, isn't what lets you do this; it doesn't have any sort of elevated privileges, and everything it can do is something you could already do yourself. The actual thing that lets you see other users' processes is that process info is stored in the `/proc/` directory, and all users have access to the `/proc/[pid]` directories that store individual process info.

If the question is instead "isn't `/proc` being world-readable a security hole," the answer is "a security hole according to what threat model?" Security holes are when someone can do something that they shouldn't be able to do. Many Unix-based systems (this behavior predates Linux) don't consider things like command line options and who's running each process to be sensitive information; making this world-readable was an intentional decision that it was not something that needed to be restricted. This behavior might be good or bad depending on your needs, but the point is that unless it's a problem on your system it's by definition not a security hole.

If you often enter passwords on a command line (that presumably you don't want other users to see), or if you don't want users to see what other users are doing, then this is a security issue, because then it lets people do something they shouldn't be able to do. On Linux, being Linux, you can modify this behavior and restrict `/proc`. If, like the designers of most of these systems, you don't see an issue with people seeing what programs others are executing, then this isn't a hole. Traditionally, that's not an issue, so most systems allow this access.

(For hidden files: They aren't actually a security feature at all; the reason they exist is convenience. Anyone who can list files in a directory can list *all* files, including hidden ones).